# Display data based on user session information

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm trying to display certain data based on session user's structure
 (STRUCT column in the table bellow

[image])

so i created a global item (:P0_STRUCT) which get the value of the structure of the session user upon login and then i wrote this PL/SQL Function in the source for the classic report

```
declare
v_query    VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
IF :P0_STRUCT is not null
   THEN 
   v_query := 'select ID_CR,
       NUM,
       DATE_AR,
       EXPEDITEUR,
       NOM_EXPEDITEUR,
       REFERENCE,
       OBJET,
       E'||:P0_STRUCT||',
       I'||:P0_STRUCT||',
       C'||:P0_STRUCT||',
       INSTRUCTION,
       DATE_INSTRUCTION,
       COPIES,
       OBSERVATION,

       NECESSITE_REP,
       REF_REPONSE
  from COURRIER_ARRIVE
  where E'||:P0_STRUCT||'= ''A Exécuter'' OR I'||:P0_STRUCT|| '= ''P/Information'' OR C'||:P0_STRUCT||' = ''P/Circulation'' '; 
  else v_query := 'select * from COURRIER_ARRIVE where ECIF = ''a'' ';

 END IF;
   return v_query ;
END;
```

the problem is that all of the three parts of the condition must be true for the function to return data on the report even thought i used OR not AND.
i want to get data if only one or all parts of the condition are true.
Please, how can this be solved?

Comment: what do you see when you print `v_query ` by `dbms_output.put_line(v_query );` for the `:P0_STRUCT is not null` case ..?

Comment: I mean is the length of 500 enough including spaces ?

Comment: Apart from a blank line between OBSERVATION and NECESSITE_REP, the rest of your query looks OK. As far as I can tell, `OR` is the right way to do what you are saying. So, what happens when you run that code? What is the result? Do you get any error? If so, which one? Furthermore, does `:P0_STRUCT` global page item contains data (it doesn't matter that you *see* it on the screen - it must be in session state. The easiest way to do that is to submit the page).

Comment: The blank is gone. still same result. the function return data only when the 3 parts 
E'||:P0_STRUCT||'= ''A Exécuter'' 
OR I'||:P0_STRUCT|| '= ''P/Information'' 
OR C'||:P0_STRUCT||' = ''P/Circulation'' 
are true. i want the function to return data even if only one part of the "OR" is true

Comment: the problem  with :P0_STRUCT is solves with the else condition (tp make the parser ignore that it doesn't hold in data at first). 
The blank is gone. still same result. the function return data only when the 3 parts 
E'||:P0_STRUCT||'= ''A Exécuter'' 
OR I'||:P0_STRUCT|| '= ''P/Information'' 
OR C'||:P0_STRUCT||' = ''P/Circulation'' 
are true. i want the function to return data even if only one part of the "OR" is true

Answer (score 1):

"Only one is TRUE" is the `XOR` function, however it does not exist in Oracle. But

```
A XOR B = (A OR B) AND NOT (A AND B)
```

So for three terms it would be

```
(A AND B AND C) OR (A XOR B XOR C) = (A OR B OR C) AND ( NOT (A AND B) OR NOT (A AND C) NOT (B AND C))
```

Replace `A` by `E'||:P0_STRUCT||'= ''A Exécuter''`, `B` by `I'||:P0_STRUCT|| '= ''P/Information''`, etc.

Comment: XOR operator checks the three operands  and returns TRUE if one or the other is true but not all of the three are TRUE. 
i want the function to return all of the three operands whether it's true or false

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?